# Filtering without pipes in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I would like to create a simple wrapper for tables with search box (and sorting in the future). So, user does not have to create a pipe etc, just uses *ngFor. I am wondering how to do it because example below does not update view.

HTML

```
<my-table [data]="statuses">
    <thead>
        <th>header 1</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let status of statuses">
            <td>{{status.username}}</td>
            <td>{{status.username}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</my-table>
```

Component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ContentChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MyTableService } from '../services/my-table.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-table',
    //styleUrls: [ '../styles/my-table.css' ],    
    templateUrl: '../templates/my-table.template.html',
    providers: [MyTableService]
})
export class MyTableComponent implements OnInit { 
    @Input() data: any;

    constructor(
        private myTableService: MyTableService
        ) {       
    }

    public filter(event) {
        this.data = this.myTableService.filter(this.data, event.target.value)
    }

    public ngOnInit() {       

    }

}
```

html component

```
<div style="width: 100%; float: left">
    <input type="text" (keyup)="filter($event)"/>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; float: left">
    <table>
        <ng-content>
        </ng-content>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Example below? :)

Comment: Ehh, stack submits form when I press enter :/ I have edited my post :)

Comment: you have to implement a pipe to filter your table. Why you dont want to use a pipe? I could send you an example in case you want to filter the table. Also just add some code to show as what you have done so far.

Comment: I don't want to use pipe because my table should be easy to use for another users

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```js
export class MyTableComponent implements OnInit { 

    @Input() data: any;
    private _filteredData: any;

    constructor(private myTableService: MyTableService) {       
    }

    public filter(event) {
        this._filteredData = this.myTableService.filter(this.data, event.target.value)
    }

    public ngOnInit() {       

    }
}
```

```html
<tr *ngFor="let status of _filteredData">
```

keep your original data as it is and use another property for filtered data.

Comment: Why? Errors? Whats the problem? :)

Comment: I have edited my question. Look, that I have a search box which must be used instead of pipe. User may not know that there is a variable _filteredData in component. He must use only variables, he created (statuses).